# Reduce number of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a method:

```
std::vector<double> minimize(double (*f)(const std::vector<double>& x))
```

that takes a function *f(x)* and finds *x* that minimizes it. Suppose I want to minimize a function *g(x, a)* (with respect to *x*) which also takes a parameter *a* as an argument:

```
double g(const std::vector<double>& x, const double a)
```

How can I do this (in c++11) using the method *minimize* if the value of *a* is known only at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use a lambda.

```
minimize([=](const std::vector<double>& x) { return g(x, a); });
```

This is assuming that you change your function to use `std::function` instead of a function pointer. Function pointers are terribly limited and can't do anything interesting at all, like this, so it's best to forget they exist.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be better style to not use default capture mode, i.e. in this case to use `[=a]` to indicate/ensure only `a` is captured.

Comment: What's the point of that? That's just manually doing what the compiler can do for you, i.e. figuring out what captures the lambda body uses. There's nothing "good style" about that. Default capture by reference is a bit more dodgy, but this is value.

Comment: Default capture by value can be *more* dodgy because you get false security. Meyers, Effective modern C++, Item 31: 'Default by-value capture lures you into thinking you’re immune to [dangling references] (you’re not), and it lulls you into thinking your closures are self-contained (they may not be).' Most relevant is if `a` is a member variable: you're *not* capturing `a` by value, but `this`. If you use `[=a]` the compiler will give you an error that reminds you of this and hopefully its dangers (`this` can become dangling, or `a` could be changed on a different thread).

Answer (score 1):

Use [labda](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lambdas-in-c11/240168241) as Puppy suggested, but additinally update `minimize` to be a function template. Using template parameter instead of std::function will dramatically speed up `minimize`

```
//somewhere in header file
template<class Function>
std::vector<double> minimize(const Function& f){
    ... 
}
...
//in any place where minimize is visible
minimize([=](const std::vector<double>& x) { return g(x, a); });
```

Comment: This is a pretty terrible suggestion. Speed is not what really matters here fundamentally, it's the flexibility. For all you know that function is actually virtual and can't be templated...